# Can't get data from a codeigniter function with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is what I've got so far:

This function that returns data from the model:

```
function get_user2()
{
    $this->load->model('my_model');
    $id=$this->input->post('users1');
    $users2=$this->my_model->get_relations($id);
    return $users2;
}
```

the model function:

```
function get_relations($usr)
{
        $this->db->where('id',$usr);
        $rel=$this->db->get('relacion');

    if($rel->num_rows!=0)
    {
        $relacion=array();
        foreach ($rel->result_array() as $row) 
        {
            $relacion[]=array(
                            'id'=>$row['id'],
                            'username1'=>$row['username1'],
                            'username2'=>$row['username2'],
                        );
        }
        return $relacion;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

and in my view:

```
<select name="users1" id="drop1">
<?php
    if($opciones!=false){
        foreach ($opciones as $row) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['user_id'].'">'.$row['username'].'</option>';
        }

    }
?>
</select>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#drop1").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "example.com/CI/index.php/evaluation/get_user2",
                data: "users1="+$('#drop1').val(),
                success: function(){
                    alert('it works!');
                }
            });
});
</script>
```

I want to fill a second dropdown with the options returned by the controller function, but the ajax request doesn't do anything so I haven't even got to that part. Can someone help me spot what's wrong? I already tested the controller and model's function and they work. And could you tell me how to fill the second dropdown's options?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you see if the ajax request is executed? You can use firebug or chrome's built in tools. Did you load the input library?

Comment: The input library is a system library, it's always loaded, that's not the problem. Use Chrome, press f12, and see what error the js console shows (or use Firefox and firebug if you already have it installed)

Answer (score 0):

Well I've a very similar code in one project to get some cities depending on the island the user choose. So wen the select changes, load the cities and enables the second select. The main difference is the way you pass the data.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#idisla").change(function(){
        if($("#idisla").val()!=""){
            var dato=$("#idisla").val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                dataType:"html",
                url:base_url+"admin/centros/municipios_select",
                data:"idislajs="+dato,
                success:function(msg){
                    $("#idmunicipio").empty().removeAttr("disabled").append(msg);
                    callback();
                }
            });
        }else{
            $("#idmunicipio").empty().attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
});
</script>
```

The function only looks cities from the selected islad (id)

```
    function municipios_select()
    {
        //el idIsla viene dado por el value del combo islas
        $isla = $this->input->post('idislajs');
        $data['municipios'] = $this->municipios_model->obtenMunicipios($isla);
        echo $this->load->view("site/municipios_select",$data, TRUE);
    }
```